# How to best test a service that who's effects get over-written by a stubbed out dependency

Tags: unit-testing, tdd

First off, my example is in php but **this is not a php question, just a question on testing best practices**

So I have this function that I would like to test

```php
public function createNewTodo(CreateTodoQuery $query): TodoResponseObject
{        
    $new_todo = TodoFactory::createNew($query->getUserId(), $query->getTitle())
        ->withDescription($query->getDescription());
    $new_todo = $this->todo_repository->save($new_todo);

    return TodoResponseObject::fromDomain($new_todo);
}
```

In order to test this function, I will need to stub out my dependency (`todo_repository`).  I want to have one test that asserts that what I get back is an instance of a `TodoResponseObject`.  Simple enough

Now the challenging bit:  I want to assert that the todo object that gets created with the parameters set in the query.  Since I'm going to be stubbing out the `todo_repository`, I can't actually do that, as my test will just assert on the values of what I configured my stub to return.  I could do something like an `assertCalledWith` type deal, but then at that point I'm going into the anti-pattern of testing that is "testing implementation, not functionality".

So how best could I get around this, and what would be the best way to test this?

Comment: I suggest you reword the title and body so that is not a primarily opinion based question.

Comment: If your code is expected to create the todo object with the parameters set in the query: why don't you create the todo object with the result of `createNew` but rather with the result of the `todo_repository->save`?  Probably because you trust `todo_repository->save` to retain those parts in its return value.  Then, why don't you configure your `todo_repository` stub just to return the object that was passed to it as argument?

Comment: Testing implementation is not an antipattern, not even with TDD.  Consider yourself implementing a sort algorithm.  The interface and functionality is the same for many sort algorithms.  That is, you have to make a decision which sort algorithm to implement.  Imagine you decide to implement introsort - think about how you would use TDD to drive you to end up with an introsort implementation without writing introsort specific test cases.

Answer (score 1):

See Sandi Metz, [Magic Tricks of Testing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=URSWYvyc42M&t=9m11s)

If you want to test that your code sent the right *message* to the factory, then the usual answer is to use a [test double](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TestDouble.html) (a mock, or a spy) that tracks the messages sent to it so that you can verify them later.

This might require changing the design of your code so that you can more easily substitute one factory implementation for another (for instance, by wrapping a decorator around the "real" factory method).

Another possibility is to split the factory invocation into a separate method, and test that method's handling of the parameters

```
public function createTodo(CreateTodoQuery $query) {
    return TodoFactory::createNew($query->getUserId(), $query->getTitle())
    ->withDescription($query->getDescription());
}
```

Changing the design of your implementation so that it better fits with your testing is *normal* in [tdd](/questions/tagged/tdd).